# Google chrome / firefox change modal/javascript based popups into internal tab messages

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extensions, firefox-extensions

I'm looking for an extension (or an option) for both `google chrome`, `firefox` that has ability to convert authentication modal dialog boxes (for example SharePoint) where it blocks the whole browser until you type in your login and password. Same goes for some banks displaying a message that it will log me out in 2 minutes blocking whole browser until I agree with it. Is there a way to force Google Chrome or Firefox to display those messages in Tabs they belong to?